# Updating id with javascript

Tags: javascript, php

Hi I am super new to php and coding in general and I have a question about updating my attribute with javascript. I currently have a loop which cycles through various assignmentNames. I need to update the id = popup-1 in order to have the loop be functional. Appreciate any help. Here is the PHP and script I have currently:

```
    if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
            echo "Assignments";
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                    echo '<div class="popup" id="popup-1">';
                    echo '<div class="overlay"></div>';
                    echo '<div class = "content">' . $row['dueDate'] . $row['className'] . '</div>';
                    echo '<div class="close-btn content" onclick="togglePopup()">&times;</div>';
                    echo '<div class = "btn-group">' . '<button onclick="togglePopup()">' . $row['assignmentName'] . '</button>' . '</div>';
                    echo '</div>';
                    echo '<script type="text/javascript">','updateId();','</script>';
            }
        }
function updateId() {
//initialize the index with 1, the item with 0 index is already in webpage.
    var i = 1; 
//Add after the element 
    var oldID = document.getElementById("popup-1");
    oldID.id = "popup-1"+i;
//Increment the index
    i++;;
}
```

Comment: Why not just create the sequential id when you create the popup in the first line of your loop?  Plus, the expression `"popup-1"+i` probably won't do what you think it will do.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You are running PHP & JS as one code chunk. In your code, you need to clearly show the compiler what is PHP code and what is JS code

Comment: hi , the script code is in a different file sorry! I just didn't separate it on here.

Comment: Will look into making it a sequential id. I am very new to coding, thank you so much for the advice!, Except I am confused on how to do it, I do not know how to add the sequential id there. Will look into it though.

Comment: `echo '<div class="popup" id="popup'.$cnt.'">';`  and have `cnt++;` at the end of the loop

Comment: Online PHP testers, like `http://phptester.net/` help to run pieces of code to see what happens.